# Why does BootstrapTable work just once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I'm making a webApp and in one screen there are two tables, the first one for the categories I store on a DB and the second for the elements that belong to those categories. Both are BootstrapTable. What I'm trying to do is that when the user clicks on a row of the first table, the items of that category will load in the second table, and I managed to do so but it just works once. If I click on the first table then the second fills up, but if i click again over any other element of the first table nothing happens. I even used console.log to see if the event works and it does, before and after the table "reload".

```
function getProductos(Categoria) {
    var id_cat=Categoria||iSeldCat;
    $('div#tableProds').bootstrapTable({
        url: '../../../controllers/classproductos?getProductos=-&categoria='+id_cat,
        cache: false,
        condensed: true,
        striped: true,
        search: true,
        language: 'spanish',
        showColumns: false,
        showRefresh: false,
        columns: [
            {
                field: 'codigo',
                title: 'C&oacute;digo',
                width: '15%'
            },{
                field: 'rutaImg',
                title: 'Imagen',
                formatter: utils().imagenProductoCRUD,
                width: '130px'
            }, {
                field: 'descripcion',
                title: 'Nombre',
                width: '35%'
            }, {
                field: 'precioventa',
                title: 'Precio Venta',
                formatter: utils().formatPriceTable,
                width: '10%'
            }, {
                field: '',
                title: 'Acciones',
                formatter: utils().buttonCRUD,
                align: 'center',
                width: '10%'
            }
        ]
    });
    console.log(id_cat + " Print");
}
```

When running that code, I get in my console `1 Print`, `3 Print` and son on, but the table just doesn't do anything.

This is the first table, including the event which as I said before, works everytime:

```
function getCategorias(){
    $('div#categoriastab').bootstrapTable({
        method: 'post',
        url: '../../../controllers/classcategorias?getCategorias=-',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        condensed: true,
        striped: true,
        search: true,
        showColumns: false,
        showRefresh: false,
        idField: 'id_categoria',
        columns: [{
            field:'id_categoria',
            title: 'ID'
        },{
            field: 'imagencat',
            title: 'Imagen',
            formatter: utils().imagenCRUD,
            align: "left",
            width: "15%"
        },{
            field: 'nombre',
            title: 'Categor&iacute;a',
            align: "left",
            width: "65%"
        }, {field: '',
            title: 'Acciones',
            formatter: utils().buttonCRUD,
            align: 'center',
            width: "20%;"
            }
        ]
    }).on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        iSeldCat=row.id_categoria;
        getProductos(iSeldCat);
    });
}
```

Any idea what it could be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach of `bootstrapping` the table again should be avoided. Handle this in the following way.

### On document ready

```
$(document.ready(function() {
    $('div#categoriastab').bootstrapTable({
        method: 'post',
        url: '../../../controllers/classcategorias?getCategorias=-',
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        condensed: true,
        striped: true,
        search: true,
        showColumns: false,
        showRefresh: false,
        idField: 'id_categoria',
        columns: [{
            field:'id_categoria',
            title: 'ID'
        },{
            field: 'imagencat',
            title: 'Imagen',
            formatter: utils().imagenCRUD,
            align: "left",
            width: "15%"
        },{
            field: 'nombre',
            title: 'Categor&iacute;a',
            align: "left",
            width: "65%"
        }, {field: '',
            title: 'Acciones',
            formatter: utils().buttonCRUD,
            align: 'center',
            width: "20%;"
            }
        ]
    }).on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
        iSeldCat=row.id_categoria;
        getProductos(iSeldCat);
    });

    $('div#tableProds').bootstrapTable({
        data: [],
        cache: false,
        condensed: true,
        striped: true,
        search: true,
        language: 'spanish',
        showColumns: false,
        showRefresh: false,
        columns: [
            {
                field: 'codigo',
                title: 'C&oacute;digo',
                width: '15%'
            },{
                field: 'rutaImg',
                title: 'Imagen',
                formatter: utils().imagenProductoCRUD,
                width: '130px'
            }, {
                field: 'descripcion',
                title: 'Nombre',
                width: '35%'
            }, {
                field: 'precioventa',
                title: 'Precio Venta',
                formatter: utils().formatPriceTable,
                width: '10%'
            }, {
                field: '',
                title: 'Acciones',
                formatter: utils().buttonCRUD,
                align: 'center',
                width: '10%'
            }
        ]
    });
}
```

### On selection of item

```
function getProductos(iSeldCat) {
    $('div#tableProds').bootstrapTable('refresh', {url: "../../../controllers/classproductos?getProductos=-&categoria=" + iSeldCat});
}
```

I have not tested this code functionality. But this should be the approach. You may refer [Bootstrap Table documentation](http://wenzhixin.net.cn/p/bootstrap-table/docs/documentation.html#methods) for property and method call details.

Comment: So have I to initialize the table without any data and then on the call is where I have to put the method and the new data I will use? I was reading the documentation and viewing some examples on the same page but didn't get it.

Comment: It did! The confusion was I didn't know where that code is supossed to be.